# Создание корпуса с категориями из TXT файлов с помощью библиотеки NLTK

Tags: nltk

Необходимо создать из TXT файлов корпус с категориями  помощью библиотеки NLTK. Файлы разложены по папкам с названием категории, также категория указана в начале имени файла.
Документация NLTK как-то не помогает, к сожалению.
После создания корпуса хотелось бы решить задачу классификации.

Comment: Я не понял - категории текстовых файлов вам известны заранее и вы просто хотите разложить файлы по папкам и переименовать? Тогда `NLTK` вам не нужен, это обычный питон. А если вы хотите классифицировать тексты и уже **после этого**  разложить файлы по папкам в соответствии с найденной категорией, то `NLTK` вам поможет, хотя для "обучения с учителем" вам нужны будут тексты, размеченные заранее по категориям. Но вы сначала определитесь, что у вас всё-таки за задача. Пока мне кажется вы не очень понимаете, что хотите сделать.

Comment: Задача обучения с учителем. Есть набор файлов документов, принадлежность которых к категориям известна. Категория известна, потому эти документы ранее уже были классифицированы пользователями. Файлы TXT, разложены по папкам с именами категорий (классов), в имя файла категория (класс) добавлены.

Comment: А, всё, я туплю с утра, вы нормально всё написали, я неправильно прочёл. Классические примеры читали? https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-nlp-text-classification-using-scikit-learn-python-and-nltk-c52b92a7c73a

Comment: В этом наборе данных каждый файл - это класс, а тексты, который надо классифицировать, внутри этого файла.

Comment: За совет и ссылку спасибо. Посмотрю, нельзя ли воспроизвести такую структуру из наших файлов.

Comment: Вам скорее всего нужно будет файлы самому из каталога читать через `glob.glob('*')` и "скармливать" их в модель для её обучения, а потом для предсказания. Ну, в общем это чисто организационные вопросы, нужно просто правильно декомпозировать задачу. Погуглите и другие статьи про `20 newsgroups classification` - это классический пример классификации текстов, разобранный многими способами на разных сайтах.

Comment: Вы очень хорошо обо мне думаете, это всегда приятно. Мне бы c NLTK как-то договориться, я бы и частность посмотрела и устойчивые словосочетания поискала. Но я на таком уровне, что у меня все разваливается, а регулярные выражения не пишутся. Даже книжка Бенгфорта "Прикладной анализ текстовых данных" мне не помогает.

Comment: За советы большое спасибо. Еще почитаю и попробую.

Comment: Вообще тут можно и без `NLTK`, вот чисто на `sklearn` пример с теми же ньюсгруппами: https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html По моему опыту `sklearn` гораздо проще и понятнее. И документация у него отличная, там много примеров и т.д.